# Parsing table in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

For learning purpose, i wanted to parse db table and save in a hash based on type for example table looks like:
[image]

source table in json format look like:

```json
[
  {"id": 1 , "type": "Atest", "ip":"10.2.0.1", "port":1234, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 2 , "type": "Btest", "ip":"10.2.0.2", "port":3000, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 3 , "type": "subtest", "ip":"10.2.0.3", "port":3001, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 4 , "type": "Atest", "ip":"10.2.0.4", "port":9999, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 5 , "type": "subtest", "ip":"10.2.0.5", "port":1235, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 6 , "type": "Ctest", "ip":"10.2.0.6", "port":1111, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 7 , "type": "Btest", "ip":"10.2.0.7", "port":2222, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 8 , "type": "subtest", "ip":"10.2.0.8", "port":3333, "description": "xyz"}
]
```

what i like to do is to parse this table with only type (Atest and Btest) and save to a hash like

```
hash_result ={type: Atest {id: 1 ,description: xyz}, type: Btest {id:2 ,description: xyz}, type: Atest {id: 4 ,description: xyz} , type: Btest {id: 7 ,description: xyz}}
```

what i am thinking is to have a switch case on type like

```
hash_result={}

when type == "Atest"
   hash_result.append(...)
when type == "Btest"
   hash_result.append(...)
```

Result:

```
hash_result ={type: Atest {id: 1 ,description: xyz}, type: Btest {id:2 ,description: xyz}, type: Atest {id: 4 ,description: xyz} , type: Btest {id: 7 ,description: xyz}}
```

But i am not sure how to do this, in the end I also like to know after i have a `hash_result`, how to search for specific `[id]` and print its type. I will appreciate any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your result hash is not a valid Hash I only assume the wanted result and give you general idea how to achieve it. Also I'm not sure if you prefer strings or symbols as the Hash keys. Since your data example uses symbols, I will stick with it.

For filtering use `Hash#select` to find an element based on ID use `Enumerable#find`

```rb
data = [
  {"id": 1 , "type": "Atest", "ip":"10.2.0.1", "port":1234, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 2 , "type": "Btest", "ip":"10.2.0.2", "port":3000, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 3 , "type": "subtest", "ip":"10.2.0.3", "port":3001, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 4 , "type": "Atest", "ip":"10.2.0.4", "port":9999, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 5 , "type": "subtest", "ip":"10.2.0.5", "port":1235, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 6 , "type": "Ctest", "ip":"10.2.0.6", "port":1111, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 7 , "type": "Btest", "ip":"10.2.0.7", "port":2222, "description": "xyz"},
  {"id": 8 , "type": "subtest", "ip":"10.2.0.8", "port":3333, "description": "xyz"}
]

filtered = data.select{ |d| %w(Atest Btest).include? d[:type] };
# => [
#      {:id=>1, :type=>"Atest", :ip=>"10.2.0.1", :port=>1234, :description=>"xyz"},
#      {:id=>2, :type=>"Btest", :ip=>"10.2.0.2", :port=>3000, :description=>"xyz"},
#      {:id=>4, :type=>"Atest", :ip=>"10.2.0.4", :port=>9999, :description=>"xyz"},
#      {:id=>7, :type=>"Btest", :ip=>"10.2.0.7", :port=>2222, :description=>"xyz"}
#    ]

result_hash = filtered.map{ |line| {line[:type].to_sym => line.select{ |key, value| %i(id description).include? key }} }
# => [
#     {:Atest=>{:id=>1, :description=>"xyz"}},
#     {:Btest=>{:id=>2, :description=>"xyz"}},
#     {:Atest=>{:id=>4, :description=>"xyz"}},
#     {:Btest=>{:id=>7, :description=>"xyz"}}
#    ]

result_hash.find{|element| element.values.first[:id] == 2}
# => {:Btest=>{:id=>2, :description=>"xyz"}}
```

Comment: instead of .find method can i directly use .include? on filtered ? let say filtered.include?(:id == 2) something like this??

Comment: @Abr You can use `filtered.find{|record| record[:id] == 2}` however the best solution performance wise would be if you store the data in the hash and use ID as a key `{1 => {:type=>"Atest", :ip=>"10.2.0.1",...}, 2 => {:type=>"Btest",...}`. Searching a hash by key should not matter on the size of the hash, using `find` or similar approach would have linear complexity with the size of the hash.

Comment: filtered.find works but i want to check if id exists in filtered otherwise return msg like id not found

Comment: ok i can do something like if !filtered.find{|record| record[:id] == 2}.nil?, is there a better way of doing this

Comment: So using find method is not suitable ? for my case you suggest i use id as key for my case

Comment: @Abr The function you are looking for is `filtered.any?{|record| record[:id] == 2}`. However this still iterates over the array until it finds a match. It will work and you wouldn't notice a performance difference for a reasonably sized dataset but the correct approach is to search hash by it's key.

Comment: One more question for learning, for instance if i have same as above data1 and data2 (different) , we apply filtering on both filtered1 and filtered2 , now if i want to check if one or more values of filtered1 exists in filtered2 and if yes save them to a new hash (only the values with common id's)